# Eclipse conditional breakpoint has compilation errors, in ThreadpoolExecutor

Tags: eclipse, conditional-breakpoint

I am trying to put a conditional breakpoint in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor class (say in getTask()) method. I tried multiple conditions, but in all conditions, this as well as other threads keep popping the following error:

### "Unable to compile conditional breakpoint - missing java project context".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQVez.png)

Could this be happening because ThreadPoolExecutor could have been compiled without debug information?

In any case, are there any other way in which i can break in this class (particularly getTask() method)? Its important for me in order to debug multi threaded application.

Comment: Are you able to get  past this issue?